# Attempting to get an http request with user input from LWC input field

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, httprequest

I am trying to allow our Salesforce Users to paste a unique number into an input field on an LWC, then let an Apex Class process a named Credential HTTP request - currently getting an error and not sure why.

I will post the code below.

Alternatively, this number they are inputting also exists on the account object but I'm struggling to pass that information through to the Apex class as well. (Prefill the input box with the number or submit the request onClick with a button that pulls the field from the account object)

UPDATE: I have updated the named credential to be the most simplistic form of the URL (which is working now) and I have added in Named Principal, a username, and the API key as the password. The Api key needs to be in the URL, but doesn't appear to be sending properly.

I have also edited the code to reflect my changes.

-- Apex Class --

```
    public class samCall {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

    public static String samQuery(Integer accountDuns) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint( 'callout:samAPI/entity-information/v1/entities?ueiDUNS=' + accountDuns + '&' + 'api_key=' );
        req.setHeader('api_key', '{!$Credential.Password}');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        return res.getbody();
    }

}
```

-- HTML --

```
<template>
    <div >

        <lightning-input type="number" label="Enter DUNS" value={dunsNumber} onchange={handleChange}> </lightning-input>

        <p>Displaying SAM Information</p>

        <template if:true={samRecord}>
                <p> Name: {samRecord} </p>
        </template>

        <template if:true={error}>
            Some error occured.
        </template>
        
    </div>
</template>
```

-- JS --

```
    import { LightningElement,wire,track,api } from 'lwc';

import getDuns from '@salesforce/apex/samCall.samQuery';
 

export default class searchSam extends LightningElement {

    @api dunsNumber;

    @track samRecord;

    @track error;

    handleChange(event){

        const userInput = event.target.value;

        this.dunsNumber = userInput;

    }

 

    @wire(getDuns,{ accountDuns: '$dunsNumber'}) 

    samData({ error, data }) {

        if (data) {

            //console.log('RecordId is'+recordId);

            this.samRecord = data;

            this.error = undefined;

        } else if (error) {

            //console.log('Error block');

            this.error = error;

            this.samRecord = undefined;

        }

    }

}
```

-- Meta --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
            <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
            <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: This question seems likely to need extensive back-and-forth to resolve, but also otherwise seems on topic, so I have [created a chat room for it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125006/discussion-on-question-by-user-11223344-attempting-to-get-an-http-request-with-u).